# Customize the return object from django rest framework serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want to customize the django rest framework serializer return object to a specific requirement. right  now it returns the fields in a single object that is not nested.

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "namespace": "steve",
    "path": "something/another",
    "value": "this is a value"
},
```

and this is what I want the outcome to look like:

```
{
    "id": 6,
    "namespace": "tempnamespaced",
    "path": "randompath",
    "value": "anothertest",
    "user": {
        "userId": "testUser1"
    }
}
```

So i want to add a nested object named user and add the userID value within the user.

the data that is returned in the userId is actually person.username
person is a model username so the data is going to look like this when it is assigned and returned:

```
"user": {
    "userId": {{person.username}}
}
```

I will attach mmy code below:

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Preference
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(),)

    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ('id', 'namespace', 'path', 'value')
```

here is the get viewset:

```
    @permission_classes((IsAuthenticated))
    def get_queryset(self):
        namespace = self.kwargs.get('namespace', None)
        path = self.kwargs.get('path', None)
        if namespace is None and path is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1)
        if namespace and path is None:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace)
        if namespace and path:
            queryset = Preference.objects.all().filter(user_id=1, namespace=namespace, path=path)
        return queryset
```

here is the mode:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from owf_framework.people.models import Person

class Preference(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    version = models.BigIntegerField(default=1, null=False)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    namespace = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    value = models.TextField(null=False)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.namespace

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'preference'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define [`to_representation()`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer) in your serializer:

```py
class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(),)

    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ('id', 'namespace', 'path', 'value')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['user'] = {'userId': instance.person.username}
        return ret
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method to your model to return the username instead of the field name.

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True, null=False)
    version = models.BigIntegerField(default=1, null=False)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    namespace = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    value = models.TextField(null=False)
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, default=1)
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.namespace

    def get_username(self):
        return self.person.username

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'preference'
```

The Serializer can now use this method.

```
class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    person = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(),)

    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        fields = ('id', 'namespace', 'path', 'value', 'person', 'get_username')
```